# OcotberCMS - "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.application_id'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, octobercms

I am getting this error message with relations but I can't find out what I need to do to stop this error.

I have an Application model with a controller and component.  In the backend I can add a new Application record.  But to view I get the error.

```
  "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.application_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`application_id` = 1 and `users`.`application_id` is not null limit 1)" on line 662 of /srv/users/sssandwich/apps/website/public/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
```

I isolated the error to appear when I add this code in fields.yaml of
Acme\Models\Application\fields.yaml.

```
# ===================================
#  Form Field Definitions
# ===================================

fields:         
    client:
        label: Client
        type: relation
        disabled: true
        select: concat(name, ' ', surname)
        span: left
```

In

```
Acme\Models\Application.php
```

I have the relations set up as

```
/**
     * @var array Relations
     */
    public $hasOne = [
    'client' => ['RainLab\User\Models\User', 'table' => 'users'],
    'cv' => ['Acme\Acme\Models\Cv']
    ];
    public $hasMany = [];
    public $belongsTo = [
    'owner' => ['Backend\Models\User']
    ];
```

Below is the database structure...

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('acme_acme_applications', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('jobs_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('application_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('owner_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('user_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('vacancy_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('ref_no', 50)->nullable();
        $table->char('status_update')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I have grep'd 'application_id' and it only appears in the db structure.  The users table is the Rainlab User plugin, but I am not sure why it trying to find the application_id in that table.

Comment: Remove the hasOne client relationship in your application, it looks like it's trying to drill down too much. Or else add the keys for it instead.

Comment: Thankyou but if I remove the hasOne client then it won't display the name of the user who submitted the application.  But I have no idea why it looks for the application_id still.

Comment: It may be trying to pull the client of the application. Try adding the keys to the client (id as foreign key, user_id as local key). I don't recognize the format, so I'm not sure how you'd add them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.application_id'...
```

I think this error is self-explanatory the Application Model is assumed to have a `application_id` foreign key because you defined a One-To-One Relation ;

If the Application Has-One User then the User's table should include an `application_id` column :

```
 public $hasOne = [
    'client' => [
    'RainLab\User\Models\User',
    'table' => 'users',
    'key' => 'application_id', // the foreign key in User's table
    'otherKey' => 'id', // Model record id
        ],
    ];
```

and you should define the inverse relation in the User's Model, a User `belongsTo`

```
 public $belongsTo = [
    'application' => [
    'Acme\Models\Application',
    'table' => 'acme_acme_applications',
    'key' => 'application_id',
    'otherKey' => 'id',
        ],
    ];
```

If you don't want to directly edit the RainLab User's plugin ( changes will be lost during updates ), have a look [here](https://github.com/rainlab/userplus-plugin) how it extends the plugin and adds multiple columns to the database .